# What's the difference between new/delete and ::new/::delete?

Tags: c++, syntax

```
new delete
```

or

```
::new ::delete
```

I'm wondering the uses of that `::` as it seems works normally if I remove them.

These are all the codes written in tutorial of auto pointer.

```
#include <cstddef>  
size_t* alloc_counter(){
    return ::new size_t;  
}  
void dealloc_counter(size_t* ptr){
    ::delete ptr;  
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can override `new` for a class, but `::new` will always seek in global scope. I.e.:

```
class A {
    void* operator new(std::size_t sz) { 
        /* 1 */ }
};

void* operator new(std::size_t sz) { 
        /* 2 */ }

void f() {
    A* a1 = new A;   // calls A::new (1)
    A* a2 = ::new A; // calls implementation 2 or compiler's new
}
```

That is described in § 5.3.4 New, clause 9:

> If the *new-expression* begins with a unary `::` operator, the allocation function’s name is looked up in the global scope. Otherwise, if the allocated type is a class type `T` or array thereof, the allocation function’s name is looked up in the scope of `T`. If this lookup fails to find the name, or if the allocated type is not a class type, the allocation function’s name is looked up in the global scope.

<sub>(as of N3797 draft)</sub>

Same applies to `delete` and `::delete`

Comment: What is the rationale behind _not_ calling an extra-for-this-type-overloaded `new`/`delete`?

Comment: @Serthy: When you allocate objects from _big shared pool_, but sometimes need temporary objects for your process only?

Answer (score 6):

`::new` and `::delete` are the operators at the global scope. You use this syntax in case you overload `new` and `delete` for your class. In the latter case, calling simply `new` inside your overloaded `new` leads to infinite recursion, as you end up calling the operator you're just defining.